# bash renaming counter loop

Tags: bash, loops, rename, counter

how can i do this in a loop?

I need to put little script in cron-tab which will take actual logs and put them in log-1 file. Rename log-1 file to log-2 file ... Bassicaly i need to have week old log files, sorted in log-1 to log-7 logs, where log-7 is day log 7 days ago and updated daily.

Bassicaly i need this in a little loop and have a problem with syntax:

```
mv log-6 log-7
mv log-5 log-6
mv log-4 log-5
mv log-3 log-4
mv log-2 log-3
mv log-1 log-2
mv logactual log-1
```

Comment: Show us your code so that we could identify the problem with the syntax.

Comment: BTW, `logrotate` does what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
for ((i=7; i>=2; i--)); do mv "log-$((i-1))" "log-$i"; done; mv logactual log-1
mv log-6 log-7
mv log-5 log-6
mv log-4 log-5
mv log-3 log-4
mv log-2 log-3
mv log-1 log-2
mv logactual log-1
```

Comment: Fast as always, but perhaps let the OP show some effort first... :-)

Comment: What syntax problem are you getting? Can you paste actual error?

Answer (score 0):

While I agree your question shows some lack of effort, I could not resist the challenge. ;)

```
for file in log-*
do
    lognr=$(echo $file | sed "s/log-\(\d*\)/\1/")
    mv "$file" "log-$(expr $lognr + 1)"
done
mv logactual log-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers, for lack of effort case, i had:

```
COUNTER=7
until [  $COUNTER -gt 0 ]; do
mv log-($COUNTER -1) log-$COUNTER
let COUNTER-=1
done
```

didn't know how to do that log-($COUNTER -1) and had trouble googling it out